# React Not considering the Context path

Tags: reactjs, axios, contextpath

I'm using React + Axios for API calls in a Spring-boot Application.

My Application context path is `/test`

When I launch my Application in the browser as, http://localhost:8080/test, the React page renders. In the page render, I'm making a `GET` call to the service that something looks like

`axios.get(api/events);`

So the Expected call Should go as http://localhost:8080/test/api/events, as `/test` is a context ROOT. But `/test` is been added in the API call.

It is simply calling http://localhost:8080/api/events which results in 404.

But when I launch my App in the browser as - http://localhost:8080/test/ (/ at the END) - Calls going as Expected

It seems the API call is considering the window location pathName instead of the Context Path.

How to make sure that all the Calls should bypass through the Context Path, irrespective whether slash present in the browser URL or not.

`axios.get(api/events); 
axios.get(/api/events);`

Both are not working, when there is no Slash at the end of the Browser URL

Answer (score 0):

you can add
"proxy": "http://localhost:port/test"
in your package.json.
This will solve the problem for development environment. I'm also looking for the solution for production builds. Cheers!